# Lines being split while decrypting file into a list

Tags: java, inputstream, encryption, crypt

Im trying to read my encrypted file and placing its decrypted contents into a list, but some lines towards the end split randomly or half way to a new line. Any ideas why it's doing this?
(In the decrypt method). Btw the buffer is 1024 if that helps.

```
public Crypto() {
    try {
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 100);
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static List<String> decrypt(String file) {
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    try {
        InputStream in = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), dcipher);
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            list.add(new String(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This can't be your actual code. `list.add(new String(buffer, 0, numRead);` statement seems to miss a closing bracket.

Comment: You're reading strings 1024 bytes long into a `List` - if you want to read line by line you're going to need to use a `BufferedReader` and the `readLine()` method, so `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), dcipher)))` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works xD. Finally what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` method on a `Stream` just reads a number of `Byte`s into a buffer. So your code reads the file in chunks of size 1024 and saves each chunk read into a `List`.

There are several ways to read a `Stream` line by line, I would recommend the `BufferedReader`

```
final List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
try {
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), dcipher)));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

One thing to note that has caught me out on numerous occasions is that the `InputStreamReader` does an implicit conversion from `Byte` to `String` - this requires an encoding. By default the platform encoding will be used, this means that your code is platform dependent. The same goes for your original code as `new String(byte[])` also uses the platform encoding be default.

I would recommend **always** specifying the encoding explicitly:

```
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), dcipher), "UTF-8"));
```

Or for the `String` constructor

```
new String(bytes, "UTF-8")
```

The same goes for any code that writes a `String` to a `File`:

```
try {
    try (final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), dcipher), "UTF-8"))) {
        writer.append(data);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This way you avoid nasty surprises when running your application on a different OS as each family use a different default encoding (`UTF-8` on Linux, `ISO-8859-1` on Windows and `MacRoman` on Mac).

Another note is that you do not close your `Stream` (or `Reader` now) - this is necessary, it can be done in a `finally` in java 6 or using the new `try-with-resources` construct of java 7.

```
try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), dcipher), "UTF-8"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(line);
    }
}
```